# Is there a way to inherit a Drupal installation profile?

Tags: installation-profiles

I want to create a Drupal installation profile based on an existing one. Is there a way to inherit the parent profile so I don't need to duplicate modules, dependencies, libraries definitions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing some research and testing I found a way to inherit Drupal installation profiles, using drush make (works in Drupal 7).

1) Apply Drupal patch #47 submitted in this [topic](https://www.drupal.org/node/2067229)

```
projects[drupal][type] = core
projects[drupal][version] = 7.32
projects[drupal][patch][] = https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/drupal-inheritable-profiles-2067229-47.patch
```

2) Set Drupal "base profile" in your **profile.info** file. My installation profile will be based in [Guardr](https://www.drupal.org/project/guardr)

```
name = MyProfile
description = MyProfile
version = 7.x-1.0
core = 7.x
base profile = guardr
```

3) Execute with Drush the make file of your base profile. Add it to your **profile.make**:

```
projects[guardr][type] = profile
projects[guardr][download][type] = git
projects[guardr][download][url] = "git://git.drupal.org/project/guardr.git"
projects[guardr][download][branch] = "7.x-1.14"
```

drush will download it and then recursively run the make file of the base profile

I found the reference in this blog [post](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/inheriting-your-drupal-profile-from-an-existing-distribution/)

Comment: It is not completely functional, I found some issues in this implementation.
- hook_install is executed in reverse order (it should be executed the base profile first)
- variables[] in base_profile.info are not being loaded

I will try to improve the patch..

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, core doesn't provide this functionality.

[Profiler](https://www.drupal.org/project/profiler) might be what you need.

> Profiler allows you to quickly and easily create new install profiles, as well as have 'Sub' Install Profiles, where one Install Profile inherits from and extends another Install Profile.

Answer (score 0):

You might install https://www.drupal.org/project/protocol distribution because this allow your profile to inherit parent profile.

Comment: Don't claim it allows something. Either quote a proper part of project page / documentation, or describe how exactly to do it.